# Selection sort doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, sorting, selection-sort

I'm sorting my array with selection sort but it doesn't work properly.
  It returns array like 2, 3, 4, 17, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13.
 
So did i write selection sort algorithm wrong? It works okay in other case but not here.

```
   <body>
  <button onclick="func()">Click</button>
</body>

<script>
  var arr = [4, 3, 11, 9, 18, 13, 6, 2];
var counter = 0;

function showarray() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var divSort = document.createElement("div");
    divSort.style.width = 30 + "px";
    divSort.style.height = 30 + "px";
    divSort.style.background = "yellow";
    divSort.style.display = "inline-block";
    divSort.style.margin = "10px";
    divSort.id = arr[i];
    divSort.innerHTML = arr[i];
    document.body.appendChild(divSort);
  }
}
showarray();

function func() {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length-1; j++) {
    var min=j;
    for (var i = j+1; i < (arr.length); i++) {
      if (arr[min] > arr[i]) {
        min=i;

      }
    }

    swap(min, j);

}
}
  function swap(smaller, bigger) {
    var tmpBigger = arr[bigger];
    var tmpSmaller = arr[smaller];
    arr[bigger] = tmpSmaller
    arr[smaller] = tmpBigger;

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + tmpSmaller).insertBefore("#" + tmpBigger);
    }, ++counter * 2000);
  }
```

Comment: where is your `swap` function ?

Comment: any reason you just dont use the native array sort method?

Comment: @Alexander this's my swap function                                                                                         function swap(smaller, bigger) {
    var tmpBigger = arr[bigger];
    var tmpSmaller = arr[smaller];
    arr[bigger] = tmpSmaller
    arr[smaller] = tmpBigger;}

Comment: @Rooster I need selection, insertion or bubble sort. It worked with bubble but not selection

Comment: @dummy seems works https://jsfiddle.net/bzvcz65v/1/

Comment: @dummy please update code in question.

Comment: I confirm as Alexander said that the example gives a correct result. What is the problem?  @Hogan, I think that line should not be changed. algorithm is looking for values smaller than at a[min], so it can move the min pointer to the smallest one found.

Comment: @trincot yep makes sense.

Comment: Yeah it works in jsfiddle but not in page I edit my question and added whole code @trincot

Comment: @dummy, the array gets sorted properly but the divs aren't. You are just moving the smaller value before the higher value, where as your algorithm is actually swapping the values (moving both elements).

Comment: @MinusFour then how can i swap divs properly?

Answer (score 0):

just sort them as numeric:

```
var arr = [4, 3, 17, 11, 9, 8, 13, 6, 2];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
alert(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This swap function will work with siblings:

```
function swap(ind1, ind2) {
    var valueOne = arr[ind1];
    var valueTwo = arr[ind2];
    arr[ind2] = valueOne;
    arr[ind1] = valueTwo;

    setTimeout(function () {
        elementSwap($('#' + valueOne), $('#' + valueTwo));
    }, ++counter * 2000);
}

function elementSwap(jq1, jq2) {
    var tmp;
    if (jq1.prev().length > 0) {
        tmp = jq1.prev();
        jq1.insertBefore(jq2);
        jq2.insertAfter(tmp);
    } else {
        tmp = jq1.next();
        jq1.insertBefore(jq2);
        jq2.insertBefore(tmp);
    }
}
```

Also, the smaller and bigger distinction don't matter in this case.

I also suggest doing the swap only if `min` is different from `j`:

```
if (min !== j) swap(min, j);
```

```js
var arr = [4, 3, 17, 11, 9, 8, 13, 6, 2];
var counter = 0;

function showarray() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var divSort = document.createElement("div");
        divSort.style.width = 30 + "px";
        divSort.style.height = 30 + "px";
        divSort.style.background = "yellow";
        divSort.style.display = "inline-block";
        divSort.style.margin = "10px";
        divSort.id = arr[i];
        divSort.innerHTML = arr[i];
        document.body.appendChild(divSort);
    }
}
showarray();

function func() {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
        var min = j;
        for (var i = j + 1; i < (arr.length); i++) {
            if (arr[min] > arr[i]) {
                min = i;
            }
        }
        if (min !== j) swap(min, j);

    }
}

function swap(ind1, ind2) {
    var valueOne = arr[ind1];
    var valueTwo = arr[ind2];
    arr[ind2] = valueOne;
    arr[ind1] = valueTwo;

    setTimeout(function () {
        elementSwap($('#' + valueOne), $('#' + valueTwo));
    }, ++counter * 2000);
}

function elementSwap(jq1, jq2) {
    var tmp;
    if (jq1.prev().length > 0) {
        tmp = jq1.prev();
        jq1.insertBefore(jq2);
        jq2.insertAfter(tmp);
    } else {
        tmp = jq1.next();
        jq1.insertBefore(jq2);
        jq2.insertBefore(tmp);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="func()">Click</button>
```